# python web server for one only one cycle

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, server

I have to work with a web service which posts its results to a url which I give in my request. In order to use the result from the web service, I want to set a one-off server which listens in a port and waits, so that when the web service posts its result to me, I can use it. Do you know a library to do that, that is, a blocking one-off http server, to capture only one request and return?

I want to do this with a simple script. I know there are web frameworks and stuff, but, as I said, I only need to get the post from the web service and use the result, as if I were working on a Python prompt.

**EDIT**

I want to use something like this:

```
request = receive_http_request(from="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
my_data = json.loads(request.body)
```

After some thought I could say I am looking for an inverse [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library.

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you're doing something manually with webhooks?

Comment: I would use a looping .ajax call. But I don't know your implementation

Comment: @nathancahill I want to analyze manually the data, in a Python prompt. This is why I need to gather the results, and I cannot do that with a web framework (I think)